# (Ethernet)Network Connect and Disconnect while on Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I was trying to connect and disconnect the laptops ethernet interface while i am running the app on the emulator, programatically.

But I am not able to perform the same. Since, the emulator is the mounted device on my laptop, it is not allowing me to perform any command outside of the emulator. I tried pushing the shellScript on to the /sdcard directory and then tried executing , but it is not working.

I am trying to run some shellScripts using java ( en0_connect.expect and disconnect.expect).

Is there any alternative to do the same, programatically.

My requirement is , I need to run it as part of my androidApp itself.

Answer (score 0):

Socket programming did the trick for me.

I created a socket client on the android running Project. This client if required sends a string "disconnect" to the server.

Server then performs the disconnect or connect operations accordingly.

Socket proramming did the trick for me. Server can perform the operations outside of the android project and execute system operations.